# Java Unexpected Async Behavior

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, java-threads

Im expecting unexpected behaviour in Java(Java 17, Spring Boot app). This method is for test and Im calling it directly from the main method.

Shouldnt the main thread get blocked at the line of thenApply() and why it doesn't?

To my Java knowledge and all I checked and researched so far **thenApply()** should be blocking, gut in my case it behaves like **thenApplyAsync()**.

```
`       System.out.println("Main Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            var otherThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Future Thread: " + otherThread);

            return otherThread;
        });

        System.out.println("Code before thenApply: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        var result = future.thenApply(res -> {
            System.out.println("Future Thread in Result: " + res);

            System.out.println("Then Apply Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            return res;
        });

        System.out.println("Code after thenApply: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            var finalResult = result.get();
            System.out.println("Code after get: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("After get result:" + finalResult);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

Logs:
Main Thread: main
Code before thenApply: main
Code after thenApply: main
Future Thread: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Future Thread in Result: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Then Apply Thread: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Code after get: main
After get...ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1`
```

Comment: Why do you think `thenApply()` should be blocking? It registers a function to be applied to the `future` similarly to the way `Stream.map()` registers a function to be applied to a stream without actually executing it.

Comment: This is the way I understood from the documentation it should work. Then what is the difference with thenApplyAsync?

Comment: `thenApply` means there is no policy regarding which thread will be used to evaluate the function. `thenApplyAsync` guarantees that the provided `Executor` (or the default executor if none was provided) will be used.

Answer (score 3):

`thenApply` *may* block the thread if the previous stage has already completed (in your case it has not). `thenApplyAsync` is guaranteed to not block the current thread even if it has already completed.

Comment: Thank you. So this is the main difference between thenApply and thenApplyAsync? And what would be the scenario of thenApply blocking the thread if the previous stage HAS been completed?

Comment: @IvanM from my testing thenApply always blocked when the previous stage was already completed.